# Where do I look to find out why it takes so long to log out of Ubuntu now that I have upgraded to 11.10?

Tags: performance, logout, gnome-keyring

Now that I have upgraded to 11.10, the logout process takes AGES (2 minutes+) and sometimes pops up a box stating that my keyring was not unlocked and asking for the unlock password.  Any suggestions on where to start looking for answers?

Comment: Do you solve this problem or are you still looking for help?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!